# Only partial theming of custom form

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've constructed a custom module to create a form. Now I'm stuck on the theming. I already have a CSS stylesheet for the form, since my company is part of the government and they have a preset branding. So I wanted to change the HTML used by the default form theme functions of Drupal thus implementing the correct style.

But only the form-tag of the form gets rendered. The fieldset and elements are not rendered. When the theme functions are removed the default theming kicks in and the form renders normally (but of course without the requested theming).

What I have tried so far:

#### Added a hook_theme function to add theme functions

```
function publicatieaanvraagformulier_theme() {
  return array(
    'publicatieaanvraagformulier_form' => array(
   'arguments' => array("element" => NULL)  
    ),
    'publicatieaanvraagformulier_fieldset' => array(
      'arguments' => array("element" => NULL)
    ),
    'publicatieaanvraagformulier_form_element' => array(
      'arguments' => array(
        "element" => NULL,
        "value" => NULL
      )
    )
  );
}
```

#### Added ['#theme'] to the form-element, fieldset-element and the form-elements

```
$form['#theme'] = "publicatieaanvraagformulier_form";
$form['groep'] = array(
  '#title' => t("Please fill in your details"),
  '#type' => "fieldset",
  '#theme' => "publicatieaanvraagformulier_fieldset"
);
$form['groep']['organisatie'] = array(
  '#title' => t("Organization"),
  '#type' => "textfield",
  '#attributes' => array("class" => "text"),
  '#theme' => "publicatieaanvraagformulier_form_element"
);
```

#### Added the actual theme function based on the default ones in form.inc

```
function theme_publicatieaanvraagformulier_form($element) {
function theme_publicatieaanvraagformulier_fieldset($element)
function theme_publicatieaanvraagformulier_form_element($element, $value)
```

I haven't included the code of these functions because even with the default themefunctions code, they don't work. Therefor I assume they are not the source of the problem.

#### The form is called

```
//Get the form
$form = drupal_get_form('publicatieaanvraagformulier');

//Add messages
$errors = form_get_errors();
if (!empty($errors)) {
  $output .= theme("status_messages","error");
} 

//Show form
$output .= $form;
return $output;
```

I haven't found similar 'complicated' examples of theming a form, but have pieced together the former from books and online searches.

Hopefully someone has an answer to this problem (point out the mistake I made).

Greetings
Jeroen